# Method showString([class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.Boolean]) does not exist in PySpark

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, py4j

This is the snippet:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
d = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", True).option("inferSchema", True).load('file.csv')
d.show()
```

After this runs into the error:

```
An error occurred while calling o163.showString. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method showString([class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.Boolean]) does not exist
```

All the other methods work well. Tried researching alot but in vain. Any lead will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an indicator of a Spark version mismatch. [Before Spark 2.3](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/9ceee6f188e6c3794d31ce15cc61d29f907bebf7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py#L310) `show` method took only two arguments:

```py
def show(self, n=20, truncate=True):
```

[since  2.3](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/62010d64826d91a30d52cdc94467a45d211bcfd2/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py#L315) it takes three arguments:

```py
def show(self, n=20, truncate=True, vertical=False):
```

In your case Python client seems to invoke the latter one, while the JVM backend uses the older version.

Since `SparkContext` initialization undergone significant changes in 2.4, which would cause failure on `SparkContext.__init__`, you're likely using:

- 2.3.x Python library.
- 2.2.x JARs.

You can confirm that by checking versions directly from your session, Python:

```py
sc.version
```

vs. JVM:

```py
sc._jsc.version()
```

Problems like this, are usually a result of misconfigured `PYTHONPATH` (either directly, or by using `pip` installed `PySpark` on top per-existing Spark binaries) or `SPARK_HOME`.

Comment: I rechecked theconfig settings, its all fine. SparkContext version is 2.1.1 and spark version is 2.3.0.                                                                                                                          Method showString() cannot take 3 arguments. What can i do further? The issue seems to be of incompatibility.

Comment: Check `PYTHONPATH` and `SPARK_HOME` environment variables  - do these point to the same installation? Did you install PySpark separately of the Spark binaries?

Comment: I am using Anaconda jupyter notebook for python and its path is : C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3  And SPARK_HOME is set as : C:\Spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7

Comment: What does `conda list pyspark` return?

Comment: It returns : C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3 .So are you suggesting that my SPARK_HOME is also set to the same ?

Comment: It shouldn't return path (alone), but a list of matching pacakges.

Answer (score 0):

On spark-shell console, enter the variable name and see the data type. 
As an alternative, you can tab twice after variable named. and it will show necessary function which could be applied.
Example of a DataFrame object.

```
res23: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [order_id: string, book_name: string ... 1 more field]
```

Comment: Thanks. It shows me 'show' function which could be applied. But the issue is with the arguments passed