# In pySpark I am getting py4j.protocol.Py4JError: py4j.Py4JException: Method isBarrier([]) does not exist

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

This exception is rising at `lines.count()`.

> Exception has occurred: py4j.protocol.Py4JError An error occurred
>   while calling o26.isBarrier. Trace: py4j.Py4JException: Method
>   isBarrier([]) does not exist   at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318) 
>   at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326) 
>   at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)   at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>   at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at 
>           from pyspark import SparkContext
>           from pyspark import SparkConf

Code:

```
    conf = SparkConf()

    conf.setAppName("First App")

    sc = SparkContext('local',conf=conf)
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    lines = sc.textFile("sample.csv")
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    lines.count()
```

Comment: This means you're mixing incompatible versions of Spark (JVM side) and PySpark

Comment: i used `pip install pyspark==2.3.2` command to install pyspark. It also installed py4j version 0.10.7

Comment: At least the Python libraries uses 2.4. See my answer to [Method showString(\[class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.Boolean\]) does not exist in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53455489/method-showstringclass-java-lang-integer-class-java-lang-integer-class-java)