# how to run spark from jupyter on yarn client

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera-cdh

I have a single cluster deployed using cloudera manager and spark parcel installed,
when typing `pyspark` in shell, it works yet the running the below code on jupyter throws exception

**code**

```
import sys
import py4j
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster('yarn-client')
conf.setAppName('SPARK APP')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
# sc= SparkContext.getOrCreate()
# sc.stop()

def mod(x):
    import numpy as np
    return (x, np.mod(x, 2))

rdd = sc.parallelize(range(1000)).map(mod).take(10)
print (rdd)
```

**Exception**

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in _do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    187         self._accumulatorServer = accumulators._start_update_server(auth_token)
    188         (host, port) = self._accumulatorServer.server_address
--> 189         self._javaAccumulator = self._jvm.PythonAccumulatorV2(host, port, auth_token)
    190         self._jsc.sc().register(self._javaAccumulator)
    191 

TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

Comment: At first glance you have Spark version mismatch, though it might be a Java CLASSPATH problem as  well. You can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53457308/10465355) to https://stackoverflow.com/q/53455489/10465355 to determine if the former is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching abit, spark used version `1.6` is not compatible with python `3.7`, had to run it using python `2.7`